# ktor client: cant catch ConnectException even when I catch all Exceptions and Throwables

Tags: android, ktor, ktor-client

I'm using ktor client to make a simple REST request, when a network exception error occurs inside the `client.get()` call, I cannot catch this error no matter what I do and it causes the app to crash.

Keep in mind, I'm NOT trying to find the cause/solution of the crash, I'm trying to figure out how I can catch the Exception so the app doesnt crash.

here are all things I've tried:

```
try {

        val response = runCatching {
            client.post("$BASE_URL/api/users/login")
        }.getOrElse {
            throw it
        }

        return Result.Success(response.body())
    } catch (e: RedirectResponseException) { // 3xx
        Result.Error(e, e.response.status.description)
    } catch (e: ClientRequestException) { // 4xx
        Result.Error(e, e.response.status.description)
    } catch (e: ServerResponseException) { // 5xx
        Result.Error(e, e.response.status.description)
    } catch (e: java.net.ConnectException) {
        Result.Error(e, e.message.orEmpty())
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Result.Error(e, e.message.orEmpty())
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        Result.Error(java.lang.Exception(), e.message.orEmpty())
    }
```

None of these is able to catch the crash.
I'm assuming the crash is happening on another thread or process and that's why I cant catch it, and that I need to add some sort of error handler to the httpClient during initialization, However I cant figure out how to do this. This is what I have so far in my httpClient Initialization:

```
val client = HttpClient(Android) {
        install(Logging) {
            level = LogLevel.ALL
        }
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json(Json {
                prettyPrint = true
                isLenient = true
                ignoreUnknownKeys = true
            })
        }

    }
```

The actauly exception that's causing my app to crash is this:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:8090
at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:147)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your problem with this code https://gist.github.com/Stexxe/d8b4b054aa4368de5484bcdfb98ed8c3